# how use Custom Membership in website and set in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web-config, membership-provider

I have Custom Membership Provider in asp.net 4. it's:

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider
{
}
```

and Custom Role Provider:

```
 public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
 {
 }
```

I use this code for set Custom Membership in web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="CustomMembershipProvider" type="Login1.Code.CustomMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="LoginDB1Entities" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="Login1.Code.CustomRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LoginDB1Entities" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>


<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
```

and this connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="LoginDB1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Code.EFModel.csdl|res://*/Code.EFModel.ssdl|res://*/Code.EFModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=LoginDB1;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

my application its working in localhost but i use this site in host and get this error:
*Server Error in '/' Application.*

Comment: Perhaps the database doesn't exist on the host. You should get a connection string from them for the database on their server. Do you have any type of logging to show you what the actual error is? Like ELMAH?

Comment: I check database and this working.

Comment: You need to provide what the actual error is.

Comment: Normally in production, you need both username and password in order to access SQL database.

Comment: my web site get only this error: Server Error in '/' Application.

Comment: @win: I use this in localhost and working but in host get error. i checked database and working. So no problem in connection string.

Comment: Can you browser any public pages in your website which doesn't require user to login?

Comment: Can you use integrated security in the connectionstring on the host? Maybe you need a username/password connectionstring?

Comment: @shahinko - As MikeSmithDev pointed out, you need to get more information from your  web server (IIS I guess). You can use ELMAH or just change setting in IIS. Is CustomError on in your web config? I would google "IIS setting to enable detailed error message".

Comment: @shahinko - And how do you know this is related to CustomMembershipProvider?